# Header download corrupt files

Tags: file, download, header, corrupt

I am always trying to download a .png file with the header statement, but the files are corrupt. The downloaded files have the same size as the original files. Here is my code:

```
     foreach($files as $dateien)
     {
         echo "<a href=Wohnungsverwaltung.php?page=Allgemeine%20Downloads&file=".$dateien.">$dateien</a></br>";
     }


$file = $_GET['file'];


$downloadfile = "admin/views/Upload/Allgemeine_Downloads/$file";
$filename = $file;
$filesize = filesize($downloadfile);

if(isset($file)){
header("Content-Type: image/png"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".urlencode($filename)); 
header("Content-Length: $filesize");

readfile($downloadfile);
exit;
}
```

Does anyone know my problem?

Comment: you might try checking if the file exists. Did you try to see what it will print without all or some of the headers? And definitely sanitize the input. You know what might happen if someone sends something like file=../../../../../etc/passwd

Comment: If you mean the HTTP HEADER command, you shouldn't be using that to download anything. It's only meant to provide metadata. If you don't mean that, what do you mean?